# QML не реагирует на изменения члена-класса C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Есть приложение с областью, которая реагирует на клик мышки:

```
MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            root.model.move(index)
            }
        }
```

Функция `move` делает, что положено, но внутри нее самой вызывается другая функция, реализованная следующим образом:

```
void GameBoard::changeStepCount()
{
    int temp = m_stepCount.toInt();
    temp++;
    m_stepCount.setNum(temp);
    emit stepCountChanged();
}
```

Объявления в классе следующие:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString stepCount READ getStepCount NOTIFY stepCountChanged)

QString getStepCount() const;
void changeStepCount();

signals:
    void stepCountChanged();
```

А вот код QML:

```
GameBoardModel  {
    id: _gm
    onStepCountChanged: {
        Qt.quit();
    }
}

Result {
    id: _info
    width: root.width
    height: 20
    color: root.color
    displayStepCount: "Step " + _gm.stepCount
}
```

Код C++ работает, значение `m_stepCount` изменяется, если проверять через `qDebug()` внутри функции `changeStepCount()`, однако не меняется `stepCount` в интерфейсе программы.

Пробовал и 
`onStepCountChanged: {
            _info.displayStepCount = _gm.stepCount
        }`

, но результата никакого.

`displayStepCount` - это `property string displayStepCount: "0"` из файла  Result.qml

Не могу понять, почему QML не реагирует.

Comment: Выглядит правдоподобно, попробуйте конечно изменить notify функцию на stepCountChanged(const QString& step_count) и передать туда при emit'e m_stepCount, также нет смысла хранить его как стрингу, qml прекрасно работает с интами, quint64 например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что проблема была в инстациировании двух разных `GameBoardModel` в основном файле `main.qml` и файле `GameBoard.qml`, где этот объект использовался в качестве модели:

```
GridView {
    id: root
    model: GameBoardModel {

    }
```

Проблема решилась в удалении из `GameBoard.qml` объекта `GameBoardModel` и передачи этой модели через основной файл `main.qml`.
То есть `main.qml` стал выглядеть так:

Было:

```
GameBoardModel {
    id: _gm
}

Result {
    id: _info
    width: root.width
    height: 20
    color: root.color
    displayStepCount: "Step " + _gm.stepCount
}

GameBoard {
    anchors.top: _info.bottom
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height - _info.height
}
```

Стало:

```
GameBoardModel {
        id: _gm
    }

    Result {
        id: _info
        width: root.width
        height: 20
        color: root.color
        displayStepCount: "Step " + _gm.stepCount
    }

    GameBoard {
        model: _gm
        anchors.top: _info.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - _info.height
    }
```